# Network Flow Problems explained in simple terms

Tags: algorithm, graph, network-flow

I am reading through Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual and am very confused about the Network Flow Problem and how to evaluate it. For starters, I can't even figure out what exactly the problem is solving. I'm assuming you're trying to send a certain flow from the source to the sink using all available nodes/edges and you want to maximize efficiency of doing so, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

The first thing that the manual explains is the Residual Flow Graph. For every edge (i, j), the Residual Flow Graph can have up to two edges:

1. An edge (i, j) with weight capacity(i, j) - flow(i, j) if capacity - flow > 0
2. An edge (j, i) with weight flow(i, j) if flow > 0

How am I supposed to know what the initial "flow" is through the source? Shouldn't there be some sort of starting point where a certain amount of "data" (or whatever) is trying to go from the source to the sink in order for me to know the initial flow going through it? Maybe I'm misinterpreting what flow even represents.

The next thing is the talk of an "augmenting path". For the life of me, I can't seem to search Google for an explanation that makes sense. An augmenting path (if I understand correctly) is a path that only uses edges with positive capacity from the source to the sink. According to the book, "the flow through a network is optimal if and only if it contains no augmenting path". How is that possible? I'm not understanding how you can get from the source to the sink without using edges with positive capacity. Again, I'm probably misunderstanding.

The last thing that I'm confused about is related to the picture in the textbook:
[image: Maximum flow in sample graph]

I'm very confused as to why a path no longer exists from S to T, at least in the directed residual graph. There are no arrows going into T, so wouldn't this show the maximum flow from T to S? I don't see how this can represent any kind of flow from S to T when there isn't even a path from S to T. Somebody please clear this up :(

Comment: Wrt to an augmenting path, imagine a flow through the network that _does_ leave a path from source to sink with positive residual (!) capacity  on each of its constituting edges. take the minimum of theses capacities over all edges of the path and send this as an additional amount along the path. you've increased the flow through the network by this amount. Note that the change does not affect edges off the path.

Comment: Wrt to the T-S/S-T flows in the figure, note that the network is an undirected graph ( ie. edge capacities do not depend on the flow orientation), so any flow is equivalent to a flow where the flow on every edge be reversed. Thus there is no real difference betwen a S-T/T-S flow in the network.

Comment: Wrt initial flow: Set the flow to 0 on all edges. Alternatively, choose a simple S-T path and set the flow on each edge to the minimum of the edge capacities on the path to have s strictly positive initial flow. Note that this initialization amounts to finding an initial augmenting path.

Comment: Wrt objective: You want a maximum capacity flow. 'Efficiency' does not make sense here unless it can be mapped to edge capacities.